# How to handle precision Decimals in Python and overcome binary representation limitations in computers?

Tags: python, math, floating-point, decimal

How to obtain precision without rounding?

For instance:

```
import math
def truncate(f, n):
    return math.floor(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n

r = lambda f,p: f - f % p
size = 3245.249999999999853146309903
y =  r(size,0.01)

print(truncate(y,2))

y =  r(size,0.001)
print(truncate(y,3))

y =  r(size,0.0001)
print(truncate(y,4))

y =  r(size,0.00001)
print(truncate(y,5))

y =  r(size,0.000001)
print(truncate(y,6))

y =  r(size,0.0000001)
print(truncate(y,7))

y =  r(size,0.00000001)
print(truncate(y,8))
# Output:

# 3245.24
# 3245.249
# 3245.2499
# 3245.24999
# 3245.25 # wrong
# 3245.25 # wrong
# 3245.24999999
```

Or

```
r = lambda f,p: f - f % p
size = 3245.249999999999853146309903
y =  r(size,0.01)
print(y)
y =  r(size,0.000001)
print(y)
y =  r(size,0.0000001)
print(y)

# outputs:
# 3245.2400000000002 # wrong
# 3245.25 # wrong
# 3245.25 # wrong
```

Or

```
from decimal import Decimal
size = 3245.249999999999853146309903

print(Decimal(size))
print(Decimal(size)-(Decimal(size)%Decimal(0.000001)))
print(int(size) - (size % 0.01))

# outputs
# 3245.25 # wrong
# 3245.249999999999853146309903 # wrong
# 3244.9900000000002 # wrong
```

I know there is a hardware/electronic limitation. However is there any way to handle this situation? Is all the computer "math" like this?

Comment: The person didn't even tried to check if the answer of the question marked as duplicated would fit this question, and closed it. I've made a research before asking it. I added the proof that the answer of the "duplicate" question DOES NOT WORK FOR THIS ONE.

Comment: 1) Fractional numbers like `0.000001` are not exactly representable with binary FP.  Perhaps the approach here of * `0.000001` then `/ 0.000001` would be better with `/ 1000000.0` then `* 1000000.0`.  I.e. Use the reciprocal as it is exact.  2) Why use `floor` vs `trunc`?  `floor` will certainly have issues with negative numbers.

Comment: Using `floor/trunc` vs `round` is questionable here.  Do you really want a _floored_ result and not a _rounded_ one?

Comment: Are you concerned here with the way the values are displayed or because you're trying to checking for equality of floating point values which differ in their representation by a small value but which you consider essentially equal?

Comment: What happens if you change `print(Decimal(size)-(Decimal(size)%Decimal(0.000001)))` to `print(Decimal(size)-(Decimal(size)%Decimal("0.000001")))`? I am not sure that is the correct syntax (I do not use Python much, and its Decimal package not at all), but the goal there is to use .000001 as a decimal numeral. `Decimal(0.000001)` may parse it to binary floating-point first, after which converting it to decimal is useless. You want to parse it directly to decimal.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes I can't round it, because, for instance, if I have 3.45829899, I can't round it to 3.458299, since it is more than what I have. Using round would make my purchase impossible, since I would not have this balance, so what I need is to "split" the number.

Comment: @andand I need the number without rounding, just splitted, not for representation, but for sending it to the system. My previous comment exemplifies the issue.